# Counting most common used words in table, filtering out stop words

Tags: mysql

I created a table that is populated by the responses people stated as the first thing that came into their mind when they viewed a photo.  I have ~1400 entries.  Now, I want to see what is the most common description.

```
CREATE TABLE descript (
wordID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
wordText TEXT(50)
)
ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"Big");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"blue");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"blue");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"fast");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"impressive");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"big");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"big");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"red");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"his");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"her");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"His");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"Black");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"black");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"black");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"blue");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"a black");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"his");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"her");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"pleasant");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"the fast");
INSERT INTO descript VALUES(0,"blue");
```

and on and on and on ....

I have to make it so it is lower case, which is done with this:

```
select LOWER(wordText) descript;
```

How do I go about having it count the most common answer and display it?  I have a few stop words (that I do not want to be included in the count such as 'a" or 'the'.  How do I go about having them not counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query is:

```
SELECT lower(wordText) as word, count(*)
FROM descript
GROUP BY lower(wordText)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You can remove stop words using `not in`, if you want to include them in the query:

```
SELECT lower(wordText) as word, count(*)
FROM descript
WHERE lower(wordText) not in ('a', 'the', . . . )
GROUP BY lower(wordText)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Alternatively, if you have them in a table:

```
SELECT lower(sw.wordText) as word, count(*)
FROM descript d left join
     stopwords sw
     on d.wordText = sw.word
WHERE sw.word is not null
GROUP BY lower(sw.wordText)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

You can learn about the stop words included with MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Comment: @RADAR . . . That *would* make much more sense ;)

Answer (score 0):

IF you do a

```
SELECT COUNT(LOWER(wordText)) FROM descript GROUP BY LOWER(wordText);
```

you should be able to see how many of each word there are.

You can add an

```
ORDER BY
```

clause to arrange them based on the count of each result

Answer (score 0):

As per getting the most frequent value you can use this query.

```
   SELECT wordText, count(*) FROM descript GROUP BY wordText  ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```